# How do I change the text of the Material Design ActionBar?

Tags: android, styles, material-design

I'm playing around a bit to make an Android app using the new Material Design, but I can't figure out how to change the color of the text on the ActionBar.

I have this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff3d00</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#dd2c00</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff3d00</item>
</style>
```

But that looks like this:

[image]

I don't really like the black text on the orange background. I tried to do this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff3d00</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#dd2c00</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff3d00</item>
</style>
```

And that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the color of the ActionBar text did change, but the background became grey, which I don't like.

How exactly am I supposed to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think in this case it's enough to change the style to *Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar*. You'll get the light interface elements, but a 'dark' ActionBar with a light title text.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does changing the windowBackground color also work? From the labeled figure here: https://developer.android.com/preview/material/theme.html

Comment: Can the text color be changed to something else?

Comment: DarkActionBar Gave me backward compatibility issues with API 17

Answer (score -1):

In your build.grade project dependences add appcompat-v7:21.0.0

```
..

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    .....
}
```

Then inherit your style from appcompat

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       ........
</style>
```